# Issue with binary search?

Tags: java, binary-search

So I'm writing a code for my CS class and it requires me to use a binary search.

However, whenever I run the code, I get an error stating [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIIIA.png)

It's saying there's an issue with my binary search, but I can't figure out why.

If you need me to I can post the other 2 classes I made but I'm really stuck as to why it's not going through.

I feel like it's a stupid mistake with my articulation or calling of the search.
thanks in advance friends.

EDIT:
Here's the requirement for the code if it helps you better.

Modify the Movies program so that it keeps the DVDs sorted by director. In order to produce efficient code do not apply sorting to keep the DVDs sorted. 
Redesign method add instead, so that it inserts the DVD into a sorted collection and produces sorted collection. 
In addition, implement an efficient method to search for given DVD by the director. Method should be called searchForDVD. It should have only String type formal parameter that provides the director that we are searching for. The return type should be an integer that specifies the index in the array where the DVD is located. When search is not successful method returns -1. Method searchForDVD should be in the DVD collection class. 
Modify main method so that at the end it also tests method searchForDVD by performing one successful and one unsuccessful search.
Display the DVD found in successful search, and write an appropriate comment otherwise.

PROGRAM RUN outline:

Display all DVDs

Add two more DVDs

Display all DVDs after adding those two DVDs

Search for specific DVD that is in the collection and display it

Search for specific DVD that is not in the collection

***Here's the code in it's entirety for this one class.***

---

```
import java.util.*;

public class DVDCollection

{
    private DVD[] collection;
    private double totalCost;

    public DVDCollection()
    {
        collection = new DVD[100];
        totalCost = 0.0;
    }

    public void addDVD(String title, String director, int year, double cost, boolean bluray)
    {
        DVD newDvd = new DVD(title, director, year, cost, bluray);
        int index = Collections.binarySearch(collection, newDvd);
        if(index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("DVD with title " + newDvd.getTitle() + " already exists.");
        }
        else {
            int index1 = -index - 1;
            collection = insertDVD(collection, newDVD, index1);
            System.out.println("DVD with title " + newDvd.getTitle() + " added.");
        }
        totalCost += cost;
    }

    private DVD[] insertDVD(DVD[] original, DVD newDVD, int in)
    {
        int length = original.length;
        DVD[] destination = new DVD[length+1];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, destination, 0, in);
        destination[in] = newDVD;
        System.arraycopy(original, in, destination, in+1, length-in);
        return destination;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        String report = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
        report += "My DVD Collection\n\n";

        report += "Number of DVDs: " + count + "\n";
        report +="Total cost: " + fmt.format(totalCost) + "\n";
        report += "Average cost: " + fmt.format(totalCost/count);

        report += "\n\nDVD List: \n\n";

        for (int dvd = 0; dvd < count; dvd++)
            report += collection[dvd].toString() + "\n";

        return report;
    }

}
```

Comment: Include the error message *in your question*.

Comment: Did you write a class `Collections` with a static method `binarySearch`?

Answer (score 1):

The API for binary search is

```
public static <T>
int binarySearch(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list, T key)
```

The list must be made of elements of Comparable interface. Is the DVD object implement the "Comparable" interface?

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you what the problem is: there is no method on Collection that takes those two parameters.

The first must be a list of some class or interface, and the second must implement Comparable. It appears that your class DVD does not implement Comparable, but that's a guess. You'll need to look up Comparable if you don't know what that is.

Answer (score 0):

The binary search method requires a `java.util.List` not an array, you can convert the array to a list by using `java.util.Arrays#asList()`, but DVD will also need to implement `java.util.Comparator`, you can find the basics for this [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly related to your question, the code creates a new, larger array for each added DVD, yet the original array starts with not 0 but 100 elements; there will always be 100 null elements in the array. You should really be using something like an `ArrayList` instead of an array anyways; you won't have to worry about resizing, and you can always get an array from the `ArrayList` if you absolutely needed one.

You are trying to use the two-argument form of `Collections.binarySearch()`. The first argument should be a `List` of DVDs. `ArrayList` is a `List` (technically, it implements the `List` interface), which is the other reason you should store the DVDs using an `ArrayList`. The second argument is the item to search for. Your code does not compile because an array is not an object of a class implementing the `List` interface. Additionally, with the two-argument form of this method, the items held in the list (the DVDs) must implement `java.util.Comparable`, whose documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you have an array, not a `List`, you should be using `Arrays.binarySearch()`, not `Collections.binarySearch()`.